# Про необновляемость вьюх во время выполнения UI-поток

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-asynctask

```
TextView.setText(""+555);  
try{TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(10);} catch (InterruptedException e){e.printStackTrace();}; 
TextView.setText(""+666);
```

Вот такой код. Должен сначала поставить на текстовое поле `555`. Подождать 10 секунд. Потом изменить поле на `666`.
Но, в деле не так. Когда запускаю прогу, то она ждет 10 секунд и сразу ставит `666`. А `555` я даже не вижу на экране.

Подозреваю что эту задачу можно решит только с отдельным потоком (Например через `AsyncTask`). Так ли это? Если это так, то просьба написать код. А то я пробую через AsyncTask, все равно `555` не вижу.

Или же есть более простое решение такой задачи?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Можно использовать класс [Handler](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html), который является дальнейшим развитием потоков в Android и упрощает код:

```
textView.setText("" + 555);
new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            textView.setText("" + 666);
        }
}, 10000);
```

С [лямбдами](https://github.com/orfjackal/retrolambda) выглядит еще лучше:

```
textView.setText("" + 555);
new Handler().postDelayed(() -> textView.setText("" + 666), 10000);
```

Comment: А можно ли вот так запустить еще и процедуру 
textView.setText("" + 555);
new Handler().postDelayed(() -> textView.setText("" + 666), 10000);
new Handler().postDelayed(() -> zapuskprocedury(), 10000);

Comment: @androman да, можно.

Comment: Думаю, в коде ошибка со скобками.

Comment: @androman думаю, что вы пытаетесь использовать второй вариант кода с лямбдами без подключения библиотеки. Все ссылки есть в ответе.

Comment: У меня пишет ошибку - Lambda expression are not supported at this language level

Comment: @androman все правильно, чтобы использовать лямбды в андроид, нужно подключить библиотеку, ссылку на которую я дал перед кодом второго варианта, или используйте стандартный код из первого варианта (без лямбд).

Comment: Супер! Все работает! Спасибо большое!

Comment: Как мне поднять тебе репутацию в знак благодарности?

Comment: @androman пометить ответ, как принятый (рядом с ответом есть галочка)

Answer (score 2):

View обновляются. Но они обновляются после того, как программа заснёт на 10 секунд. Так что это нужно делать, действительно, в другом потоке.

`AsyncTask` в данном случае - слишком тяжёлая артиллерия! Можно создать анонимный класс, в котором будет выполняться в новом потоке.

Как-то так:

```
textView.setText("" + 555);
Thread myThready = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(10000);
            } 
            catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            textView.setText("" + 666);
        }
    });
myThready.start();
```

P.S. Не называйте переменные с заглавной буквы.

[Использование метода sleep()](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/338436/%D0%98%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B0-sleep)